# Icemaker tubing won’t snug in-compression nut

Tags: ice-maker

I can’t get the icemaker tubing pictured below to snug inside the compression nut. Can tighten but, but tubing keeps slipping out. Any suggestions?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you missing the inner compression ring (ferrule)? Disassemble the fitting and take another picture of all the pieces for us, please?

Comment: No, I am not missing ferrule. Picture in original posting.

Comment: You have a ferrule that needs to be replaced.  They pretty much are "one shot", as they compress slightly when the nut is tightened.  (The ferrule is the round part that you insert the tube thru, you have the self contained version that is attached to the nut---the ferrule is not the barrel piece that slides inside the tube. ) It's normal to have to replace that piece anytime you disconnect the tubing.

Comment: @Tyson  I don’t know if tubing is not go far enough down in where it is suppose to or not. The ferrule doesn’t seem to want to clamp onto tubing. Is there some alternative to compression nut setup while still using plastic tubing?

Comment: The last icemaker I hooked up had a bad nut that destroyed two ferrules and leaked on both. It worked fine with another nut and ferrule.

Comment: Does that valve have a brass piece that the compression nut is threading on to?  It looks all plastic and that wouldn't work.

Comment: I also am not liking the look of the shredded black plastic at the nut/valve location (or the bit inside of the nut). I would say that your inability to tighten the nut enough to compress the ferrule is related to bad threads on the valve where the nut connects.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it  That is suppose to be Teflon tape. I have heard good and bag things about it in regards to compression nut fittings. My next try will be without it on there.

Comment: @JPhi1618 The valve does have a threaded area that is all metal. I just don’t have a picture of it with compression nut off of it.

Comment: @ArchonOSX I am going back with new nut, sleeve, and ferrule. The one I had before had an integrated nut and ferrule together, but this one I am trying next will have these 3 parts separate. Also, I am going to run a stainless steel icemaker line from this part up to place behind fridge where I can reach easily. From there, I was going to connect to a union piece that will tie into plastic tubing that goes to icemaker shutoff valve across the room. I think it will be easier for me to connect to this part with stainless hose and it will more likely leak at union part that I can check

Comment: @ArchonOSX occasionally. This will eliminate having to deal with compression nut, ferrule, and sleeve at this location (at the valve) and instead put the more likely place to leak (union location) higher up the fridge that can be more easily checked. I would go stainless steel hose all the way to water supply, but that would entail having to drill hole into bottom of kitchen cabinet, and possibly ceramic tile.(I am not sure if line goes through tile or baseboard). It is too difficult and a mess to try to replace tile under kitchen cabinet. That was why I stuck with plastic tubing to supply.

Comment: @ArchonOSX . Even if in baseboard, it would still entail making a large cut into bottom of cabinet to see where line is going. Sorry for such long comment.

Comment: To make a long story short, I removed all plastic hose and went with stainless steel icemaker hose. Right now, it isn't leaking.